# PushSharp notifications to Apple's APNS not working, not throwing any exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I have no clue why this isn't working and it's not throwing any errors either. None of the subscribed events are ever triggered (including `OnNotificationSent` and `OnNotificationSendFailure`). The code is almost identical to PushSharp's [sample code in GIT](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/PushSharp.Sample/Program.cs), the only difference is that it's running inside a thread:

```
public class MyNotificationService
{
    ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger("");
    PushService _PushService;
    public void Start()
    {
    PushService _PushService;
    byte[] appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes("myCert.p12");
    _PushService = new PushService();
    _PushService.Events.OnChannelCreated += Events_OnChannelCreated;
    _PushService.Events.OnChannelDestroyed += Events_OnChannelDestroyed;
    _PushService.Events.OnChannelException += Events_OnChannelException;
    _PushService.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired;
    _PushService.Events.OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged += Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged;
    _PushService.Events.OnNotificationSendFailure += Events_OnNotificationSendFailure;
    _PushService.Events.OnNotificationSent += Events_OnNotificationSent;

    _PushService.StartApplePushService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(false, appleCert, "myPass"));
            _MainThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                try 
                {
            var nt = NotificationFactory.Apple()
            .ForDeviceToken("60A378B0FF0628FB52461C6F9F2CEDAA29A05D52F97EF2E811")
            .WithAlert("Test")
            .WithSound("default")
            .WithCustomItem("data", "some other data")
            .WithBadge(7);
            _PushService.QueueNotification(nt);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        _log.Error("In main thread", e);
                    }
                }
            });
            _MainThread.Start();
    }

    static void Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionIdChanged(PlatformType platform, string oldDeviceInfo, string newDeviceInfo, Notification nt)
    {
        //Currently this event will only ever happen for Android GCM
        _log.Debug("Device Registration Changed:  Old-> " + oldDeviceInfo + "  New-> " + newDeviceInfo);
    }

    static void Events_OnNotificationSent(Notification nt)
    {
        _log.Debug("Sent: " + nt.Platform.ToString() + " -> " + nt.ToString());
    }

    static void Events_OnNotificationSendFailure(Notification nt, Exception notificationFailureException)
    {
        _log.Error("Failure: " + nt.Platform.ToString() + " -> " + notificationFailureException.Message + " -> " + nt.ToString());
    }

    static void Events_OnChannelException(Exception exception, PlatformType platformType, Notification nt)
    {
        _log.Error("Channel Exception: " + platformType.ToString() + " -> " + exception.ToString());
    }

    static void Events_OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired(PlatformType platform, string deviceInfo, Notification nt)
    {
        _log.Debug("Device Subscription Expired: " + platform.ToString() + " -> " + deviceInfo);
    }

    static void Events_OnChannelDestroyed(PlatformType platformType, int newChannelCount)
    {
        _log.Debug("Channel Destroyed for: " + platformType.ToString() + " Channel Count: " + newChannelCount);
    }

    static void Events_OnChannelCreated(PlatformType platformType, int newChannelCount)
    {
        _log.Debug("Channel Created for: " + platformType.ToString() + " Channel Count: " + newChannelCount);
    }

}
```

Again, none of the events are getting triggered (nothing logged, breakpoints not hit). Curiously, calling `StopAllServices` hangs forever, apparently without doing anything. I have checked my provisioning profile and cert several times and can't find anything wrong with them. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

**Turns out the problem can only be reproduced when I run it from a Windows Service .Net project. From a console application, everything works fine. I thought it was a permissions issue that was blocking network access, but I couldn't make it work,.**

Comment: i keep getting a red line under `PushService` am i missing something to include?

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem!  I was using push sharp in a dll that was referenced by my exe.  I fixed the problem by adding the following to my app.config:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Make sure the Newtonsoft.Json dll is in your bin folder!

Comment: a little more info for this answer: I removed the older json reference on my project, and added a ref to the newer json dll (that came with pushsharp), then did the listed changes to my config file and it started working

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I've used PushSharp in my ASP.Net MVC application . Make sure that the version of Newtonsoft.Json in your application and in your version of PushSharp is the same.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I was getting no events fired except channel created, then it would chug on and on without ever timing out or throwing an exceptions. Turned out the web project was referencing an older version of Newtownsoft - removed old DLL and added binding redirect to new version and boom, push notification received. Not sure if it made any difference, but I also has a reference to the older JdSoft.APNS library (PushSharp's predecessor), which I also removed at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Does your service run as "LocalSystem" ? If no, try to install it as "LocalSystem".

Perhaps the service have no network access, so no connection to Internet or Database.

Btw, the device token seems really short but if it works as a console application, it should work as a service.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

I have same problem. No events are triggered but notification are delivered. Still looking for answer.
Maybe [this link](http://redth.info/the-problem-with-apples-push-notification-ser/) would help.

**Second** (about "StopAllServices hangs forever")

Maybe [this](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/211) will help. In short - no empty device token should be provided

Comment: I had the problem with no events triggering. Turns out it was because I added the event handlers after calling `RegisterService`. They must be added before.